# Turning relativenumber option off/on when opening/closing the gdb terminal window

Tags: vimscript

When I was not sure about how to do this, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60731020/5825294) on StackOverflow, the body of which is the following:

> As regards line numbers, when doing normal file editing, I prefer to
>   have the following setting
>
> ```
> set number
> set relativenumber
> ```
>
> because the former tells me where I am, the latter helps me using
>   <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> effectively.
>
> However, when [debugging with
>   `gdb`](https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/2019/05/debugging-in-vim/),
>   using the `termdebug` package and the `:Termdebug` command, I often
>   want to set breakpoints; hence, I'd like to turn the latter option
>   off, executing the `set norelativenumber` command on a global scope,
>   so that all files I'm editing show the actual line numbers.

Reading the answer, and Vim help pages a bit more, I ended up with the following solution, which is now part of my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" Source the termdebug plugin
packadd termdebug

" Add mapping to load termdebug
noremap <silent> <Leader>td :call MyTermdebug()<CR>

" turn off relativenumber,
" start Termdebug,
" and create autocmd to turn relativenumber back on
function! MyTermdebug()
  call SetRelNumInAllWin(v:false)
  augroup ClosingDebugger
    au!
    autocmd BufUnload !gdb call SetRelNumInAllWin(v:true)
  augroup END
  Termdebug
endfunction

" set/unset relativenumber in all windows if flag is v:true/v:false
function! SetRelNumInAllWin(flag)
  let current_win_id = win_getid()
  tabdo windo call SetRelNum(a:flag)
  call win_gotoid(current_win_id)
endfunction

" set/unset relativenumber in current window if flag is v:true/v:false
function! SetRelNum(flag)
  if &number
    if a:flag
      set relativenumber
    else
      set norelativenumber
    end
  end
endfunction
```

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things off the top of my head:

Use mode-specific mappings, so `nnoremap` limits the mapping to normal mode. (Great job on the use of non-recursive mappings.)

You can access options as vimscript variables with `&relativenumber`. `SetRelNum` is sort of unecessary: I would have written

```
tabdo windo let &relativenumber = a:flag
```

(And if that doesn’t work because of some odd scope rule, you can `exec` it with everything but `a:flag` in quotes. You may have to pass `0`/`1` instead of `v:false`/`v:true` etc.)

Comment: Concerning `nore`* I have just absorbed the lesson "use non-recursive mappings by default, unless you need recursion **and** you really know what you are doing". That oneliner you suggested is great! I'll check and adjust if needed.

Comment: Yes, I had to use 0/1 instead of `v:false`/`v:true`. However I am thinking about a usability contraddiction in my solution. Since I want to take advantage of `rnu` when navigating the files, and I want to deactivate it just when I'm in the `!gdb` window where I run the `break` command, it would make sense to set and unset `rnu` in all windows everytime move from/to the `!gdb` window.

Comment: There are some BufWinEnter style events you can look into for that

Comment: Yes, but I kinda remember that the termdebug buffer has something special, as regards the events. If I have issues, I'll post a question on stack overflow.

Comment: Ok! Remember [vi.se] exists as well!

Comment: I was wrong, using those events with the gdb window seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that deactivating `rnu` when I start `:Termdebug` is unproductive, as the option remains inactive even when I'm navigating the scripts while the `!gdb` window is open.

So I ended up with this solution, where `rnu` is off only if the cursor is in the `!gdb` window; as soon as the cursor moves away from it, `rnu` is turned on.

```
" mapping and function to start gdb and activate "smart" relativenumber
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>td :call TermdebugAndRelNumOff()<CR>
function! TermdebugAndRelNumOff()
  augroup ClosingDebugger
    au!
    " set/unset rnu when leaving/entering gdb window
    autocmd BufLeave  !gdb call SetRelNumInAllWin(1)
    autocmd BufEnter  !gdb call SetRelNumInAllWin(0)
    " delete the augroup (and its autocmd-s) when closing gdb
    autocmd BufUnload !gdb au! | augroup! ClosingDebugger
  augroup END
  " start Termdebug
  Termdebug
endfunction
```

**NOTE**

The use of `windo` has the undesirable behavior of altering the window which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> will jump to: once I move *to* the `!gdb` window from `ThisWindow`, those keys will jump to the bottom-right window instead of to `ThisWindow`. I'm trying to address this annoying thing [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26852/how-can-i-alter-the-window-to-which-ctrlp-will-jump-to).

**NOTE2**

Since moving away from the `!gdb` window makes no sense if that window is not in the current tab, and since moving to it from a tab which does not contain it is unlikely (or is it non-sense too?), I suspect that `tabdo` can be avoided entirely in the definition of `SetRelNumInAllWin` given in the question.